# Hide divs based on a wildcard or text entered in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, html, hide

All.  I'm a noob at working with Javascript and haven't been able to find posts on what I'm looking to do.  Let me set the stage, I have a page on an internal Confluence wiki that lists out all 500+ vendors.  I would like to create a form that would allow users to enter a keyword into a text box and have the page only show the vendors with that match.  For example, if the vendor div contains the words "Joe Schmoe", only the vendor divs with that word will show.

As I mentioned, this is being used on a Confluence wiki site and I've had a real problem trying to get jquery to work in the environment-especially with IE.  I'm hoping to find a reasonable js solution that I can use.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide us with some HTML, a mockup not the whole thing? Have any of the code that you have tried? Or what was the problem you had with jquery?

Comment: @Xotic750 I was trying to go into writing the code with the idea in mind. The problem I find with jquery is that some of our intranet users do not have internet access, so the links to apis don't always work. I was able to adapt something I found at http://css-tricks.com/ for their filterblock demo.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I understand your jquery problem, but that is no problem, javascript can do what you want, you don't need a 3rd party library. But can you show me a sample of your Conference page HTML layout. It would also be good, even if it was with jquery, to show any javascript that you have attempted.